# File could not be edited - GitHub Pages

Tags: git, github

I am creating a [GitHub Pages site](https://github.com/tusharjoshi1/tusharjoshi1.github.io) and  I am unable to commit any changes to the `.md` file. Whenever I try to commit any changes, I get a notification that says:

> File could not be edited

For example, it is not letting my take the phone number out of `contactme.md`.

Comment: Could you explain the problem better? I see the phone number, can't you copy paste? I am a bit confused what your issue is to help you with github.

Comment: If you want to edit it directly you can and propose a file change. directly to a file on github. Is this the problem?

Comment: So when I go the contactme.md>Delete the phone number>Commit Changes

Comment: I get the notification saying file could not be edited in red at the top

Comment: I just created a PR to remove the telephone number: https://github.com/tusharjoshi1/tusharjoshi1.github.io/pull/1 Does it allow you to merge that PR?  Can't think why you wouldn't be able to do this on your own though.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to go to the file you want to change, in this case your `contactme.md` file `contactme.md`. You then click the pencil icon on the right to begin editing your content. I added the following:

```
Test: 905
```

You will see on your github that there is a new merge request by me.

Now that we have a change we scroll down to `Propose File Change` , I like to put a short detailed description such as Contact Change as it is best practice to have a detailed but short description. After that you can leave an additional extended description, this is also by best standards to leave a detailed description on the changes made so that the person merging understands what changes you made. If you notice this looks similar to a `commit` when you are adding descriptions about the change. When you are done click the button Propose File Change.

When that is done it is the same as when you update a `branch`, you will see at the top it says `Comparing Changes` and if there are no conflicts that it is `able to merge**`. Now we click the `Create Pull Request` button in green. As you see our short description and extended description if you decided to write one is there. We simply click on the `create pull request` button.

The rest should be easy if you have worked with branches and merging code before.

Comment: Let me know if this fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

They had issues with their git cache, works fine now.

Comment: You should accept an answer as correct for the question. Otherwise it remains open

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I was able to fix it by choosing second radio button with create new branch for this request instead of directly committing to gh-pages default option. Took me few minutes to click through the create pull request and merge option approve buttons.